# php mail function

Tags: php, email

I got a strange behavior from the mail function in php 
here is the code :

```
$header = "From: aa@aa.com\n";
 $header .= "Reply-To: bb@bb.com\n";
 $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=$alt_boundary\n"; 
 $header .= "Mime-Version: 1.0\n";
 $header .= "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion()."\n";
 $header .= "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8\n";

 $send = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

but the email i receive have a from address from the main admin of the server like : user123@s12panelboxmanage.com

why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it's because you set a variable **$header**, but pass to mail() variable **$headers**. If it's not the cause, try inserting \r\n instead of \n.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the -f option in the mail function too to set the (valid) sender:

```
        $header  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0'."\n";
        $header .= 'Content-type: text/'.$contentType.'; charset=iso-8859-1'."\n";
        $header .= 'From: '.$from."\n";
        $header .= 'Reply-To: '.$mailFrom."\n";
        $header .= 'X-Mailer: PHP '.phpversion()."\n";
        $header .= 'X-Sender-IP: '.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."\n";

        mail($to,$subject,$message,$header, "-f aa@aa.com");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$to      = 'user@domain.com';
$subject = 'Subject';
$message = 'This is a test';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@yourdot.com' . "\r\n" .
   'Reply-To: webmaster@yourdot.com' . "\r\n" .
   'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```